# How to control music playing on my phone from my computer?

Tags: music, music-management, smartphone

Is there any way to control music on a phone from a computer?

It would be amazing to be able to type something like "Play house album" in the command line or some other computer interface, and have the appropriate music start playing on my phone (combining the mobility of a phone with the efficiency of a computer).

How can I do this?

Comment: Can u suggest what have you tried ?

Comment: Android or Apple?

Comment: Apple if possible.

Comment: V Look at my answer below then. I have an Apple version. V

Comment: Your question is several years old and has received three answers so far based on differing interpretations, none of which apparently answers what you're looking for.  It isn't clear if you are talking about streaming content or using the computer like a remote control for the phone, or even why you would want music from the phone when it is at your computer and you, presumably, have access to better quality sound.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a radio broadcast server on your computer and start listening to that on your phone. There are many options out there, for example [ShoutCast](http://www.shoutcast.com/BroadcastNow).

Some online radio software allows you to control your playlist remotely, so you can also control the PC transmission from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

Well assuming you have Android, you can try AirDroid, or many other apps out there that let you remote admin your device from a computer.

[image]

I chose this one simply because it is free and works over WiFi but of course you can choose your own flavor.

Simply install it, connect via WiFi, and then it provides you the IP address and PW to enter on the PC side and you can do everything from your computer.

**Apple**

Install Veency on your iPhone:

[image]

Open it and enable your WiFi. Veency is simply a VNC server tool. Once you have that, connect to your phone via a VNC client:

[image]

Lastly, accept the request:

[image]

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Eric, maybe mention for the iPhone solution you have, the user needs to jailbreak to install veency.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Airdroid. Airdroid has added a new feature called AirMirror. AirMirror requires usb debugging enabled on your device. This is a one time process. Once the usb debugging is enabled no need to connect a usb cable. Phone's screen can be seen as well as controlled from web browser over a WiFi or internet connection.

Go to http://web.airdroid.com and login. There you should be able to see an app called AirMirror. See the screenshot below.

[image]

When you click on AirMirror you'll get the setup instructions. After successfully configuring you'll be able to operate your phone right from computer's web browser.

The AirMirror screen will look like below: 
[image]